# Handle multiple html file in angular 4

Tags: angular

I want to call differnet html file in Angular4.
In my project I have created directory abc. 
Directory structure is like :

```
 abc-->app  
       src
       Index.html
       abc.html
       *.css files
       *.js files
       *.json files
       *.ts files
```

I want to call `abc.html` page insted of `index.html`.
How can do this?

Is it possible in Angular 4?
If yes than how?
Please suggest me and if possible than provide an example of it.

Comment: If you mean that you want to replace the "index" file from `index.html` to `abc.html`, just go to your `.angular-cli.json` (angular < 6) or `angular.json` (angular 6+) and change the "build -> options -> index" to point to `abc.html` instead of `index.html`.

Comment: @kha ohh great! awesome! Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your angular-cli.json:

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "abc.html", <----- Here you can specify the name
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you for suggetion!